# How to loop first() in laravel

Tags: json, api, laravel

### Context :

I make an Json api with laravel 5.1 to fetch all of categories and sub categories

and the relationship between categories table and subcategories table is ManyToMany

---

### Code :

#### Categories model :

```
 public function subcategory() {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Subcategory::class);
 }
```

#### Subcategory model :

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Categories::class);
}
```

#### Api Controller :

```
$response = Categories::with('subcategory')->first();
return $response
```

---

### Problem :

I want loop $response to get all data not only the first one

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

```
$response = Categories::with('subcategory')->take(-1)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `first` method which retrieve only the first model from Categories. In order to get **all** the records, you should use the `get` method like so:

```
$response = Categories::with('subcategory')->get();
```

Now the $response object will be a Collection of Eloquent models.

The `get` method is usually the last method of your queries, that acts like: **run the query now please Eloquent**

Take a look of the documentation about [Eloquent Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-collections)